# Substitution of Unicode character classes in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, unicode

I have a regex for validating a password in my javascript app , which is as follows :

`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$^.*()_])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$^.*()_]{8,64}$/gm`

This essentially accepts passwords containing at least one uppercase letter , one lowercase letter , one number and a special char , along with a length between 8 and 64 characters .

I wish to re-write it in Java using the [Unicode classes provided here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

How do I go translating this JS regex to its java equivalent  ?

P.S : A translation of a js regex for a weak password is provided here for reference

JS Regex without unicode classeS :

`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$^.*()_]{8,64}$/gm`

Regex translated with Unicode classes :

`^(?=.*\\p{Ll})(?=.*\\p{Lu})(?=.*\\p{N})[\\p{L}\\p{N}]*`

Comment: That regex is horrible!  Surely it would be better to do it using plain Java code; i.e. iterate the string and count characters in each of the nominated character classes.

Comment: @StephenC I share your concern too , but it'd be concise to use Unicode character class constants here , as it'd be a nightmare to actually distinguish between upper/ lowercase , special chars of all possible languages by enumerating all possible characters that might fall in either of these classes .

Comment: There is a method to test if a character is in a given Unicode character class.  You don't need to code the character testing as a monstrous switch statement, or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
^(?=.*\\p{Ll})(?=.*\\p{Lu})(?=.*\\p{N})(?:(?=.*\\p{P})|((?=.*\\p{S})))[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{S}]{8,64}$
```